# Kitchen sink tap

Tags: faucet, kitchen-sink, copper

I try to replace the tap myself but not successful. I just only remove the flexible pipe. Please see attached photo showing the tap details. Could anybody see this type of tap? And how to remove it? Many thanks[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you see what is in the two smaller holes on the corners?  Looks like they might be screw heads, but the detail isn't clear.

Comment: I try to check it tomorrow, thanks

Comment: What is the actual problem you're having? It _appears_ that you should just be able to pull the faucet straight up now, but, based on your description & photos, it's hard to know where you're stuck.